# How to abort an ongoing yiiGridView update call?

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to implement an instant search mechanism using the Yii framework.
What I want to do is catch key events and update the search term every time. It is working but problems  will occur depending on user's typing speed. What I need is a way to abort ongoing update calls, so that only the last search and grid view update call will matter.

Here's the code

```
var runningQSRequest = false;
var qsrequest;
function activate_quicksearch() {

    if (runningQSRequest){
        qsrequest.abort(); //this doesn't work in Yii framework
    }

    runningQSRequest = true;
    qsrequest = $.fn.yiiGridView.update('products-grid', {
        data: $.cookie('filter_query') + '&Products[name]=' + escape($("#quick-search").val())
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of aborting the request, try [throttling](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)